# MVC4: Show error in JQuery Modal when error occurred in controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to show a partialview as jQuery modal when error occurred in controller. After submit the form I need to check a validation, if validation fails then show the partial view in jQuery model popup.

### Edit.cshtml

```
 <div class="form-actions">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Save changes</button>
   @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Index", new {id=Model.Contact.Number}, new { @class = "btn " })
 </div>
```

MemberController.cs

```
 [HttpPost]
 [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
 public ActionResult Edit(Activity activity)
 {
    try
    {
        byte[] committeeMemberSpeId = Convert.FromBase64String(activity.Id);
       var committeeMember = db.Committee_Member.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Committee_Member_Id == committeeMemberId);
       if (ValidateEndDate(activity))  //Show here PartialView("ErrorDetail");
       if (ModelState.IsValid)
       {
          if (committeeMember != null)
          {
              ....
              ....
              db.Entry(committeeMember).State = EntityState.Modified;
                        db.SaveChanges();
                        Success("Your information was saved!");
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = committeeMember.Customer_Number });
            }
        }
        ViewBag.Roles = TempData["Roles"];
        TempData["Roles"] = TempData["Roles"];
        return View(activity);


      }             
      catch (Exception exception)
      {
           Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(exception);
           PartialView("ErrorDetail");
      }
  }
```

How can we do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can  make your post with an Ajax request and return Json to the view from the action, and then in the callback of your jquery Ajax call display the error in the dialog:

```
 [HttpPost]
 [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
 public ActionResult Edit(Activity activity)
 {
    //Do stuff

     return Json(flag, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

`flag` is just a simple class that has Error and Success strings/booleans which will be used to display the result to the user.

```
public class Flag
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }//determine whether the call succeeded or not
    public string Error { get; set; }//show some detailed error message
}
```

Then the following ajax request in your view:

```
function serializeAndSendLoginForm() {
    var form = $("#logOnForm").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: '<%: Url.Action("LogOn","Account",new{area="Security"}) %>',
        type: 'POST',
        data: form,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.Success) {
               //do more stuff
            } else {
              showDialog(data.Error);
            }

        },
        error: function () {
           alert("error");
        }
    });
}
```

Function for loading the dialog:

```
function showDialog(message){
        var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
               .html(message)
               .dialog({
                   autoOpen: false,
                   modal: true,
                   height: 625,
                   width: 500,
                   title: "Login Result"
               });
        $dialog.dialog('open');
}
```

You can return additional info from your controller to the view using some container class (instead of the flag variable in my answer) and display the additional error details to the user.